# How to disable double click zoom for d3.behavior.zoom?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I do not want [d3.behavior.zoom](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-zoom) to add the ability to double click zoom on my graph. How can I disable this behavior?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/Ld6Uz/) with the unwanted behavior.

I have tried the following without any luck.

```
 d3.behavior.zoom.dblclick = function() {};
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can disable the double-click behavior by removing the zoom behavior’s dblclick event listener. Looking at your code, you’ve assigned the zoom behavior to the SVG element. So you could say:

```
d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```

Or, together with where you register the zoom behavior:

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", update)).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
```

You might also want to move the zoom behavior down to a [G element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) rather than putting it on the root SVG element; I’m not sure it will work correctly on the root SVG, since the SVG element doesn’t support the [transform attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute).

Comment: This does not appear to work, would it be possible to clarify

Comment: Works for me too but the docs should have answered this question for me hours ago.

Comment: This does not work for me as of version 3.4.12. D3 seems to reject even setting a listener on the `dblclick.zoom` event

Comment: Actually I got it working. You need to add the dblclick listener *after* the zoom is registered on the element. Thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25024855

Comment: The first line is the right answer `d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null);`

Comment: This doesn't disable double-tap on touch devices. From what I can see from the code, disabling it is tricky, as it's just an interval between `touchstart` events, or am I missing an elegant solution? :)

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to set up a proxy function. Store the default (target) event, and then register a proxy event instead. The proxy will then enable / disable the target event using whatever logic you need:

```js
svg.call(zoom);
var dblclickTarget = svg.on("dblclick.zoom");
var mouseScrollTarget = svg.on("mousewheel.zoom");

function eventProxy(fn){
  return function(){
    // Enable events if enableEvents=== true
    if(enableEvents){
      fn.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  }
};

svg.on("wheel.zoom", eventProxy(dblclickTarget))
   .on("mousewheel.zoom", eventProxy(mouseScrollTarget));
```

By applying the proxy pattern in this way, you can simply change the "enableEvents" variable to enable or disable the events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selected answer works in versions less than 5 but just in case this is how I resolved my issue version 5.15.x

using this .on("dblclick.zoom", null); is noted in the documentation but it actually threw an error when I tried to use it (can you believe the nerve of my app? lol).

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/main/README.md#zoomTransform

Instead of using the dblclick.zoom approach, .filter did the trick for me.

I am already using double-click events for other user needs. So there are specific instances in which I do not want the double click zoom to occur.

```
D3.select('svg')
      .call(D3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-5, 8])
        .extent([[0, 0], [300, 300]])
        .on('zoom', () => {

          D3.selectAll('g')
            .attr('transform', D3.event.transform);

          this.updateAfterInit(this.root);

        })
        .filter(() => {


          const foundNode = this.N.findNodeByID(D3.event.srcElement.id.split('_')[1])
          if ( !!foundNode && D3.event.type === 'dblclick' && foundNode.data.type === 'SearchRelationspec') {
            return false;
          } else {
            return !D3.event.target.classList.contains('drawarea') && D3.event.type === 'dblclick';
          }
        })
```

Comment: Not true. Setting `"dblclick.zoom"` to `null` still works in d3 v7 (with d3-zoom v3). Perhaps you did it before .call? [d3-zoom docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_duration)