# How to disable pan for d3.behavior.zoom?

Tags: d3.js

This question looks quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom), but I am still not able to figure out whether it is possible to use d3.behavior.zoom but without the pan ability. In other words I just want to zoom-in/out using the wheel only.

The reason for this is that I want to be able to brush on the "zoomable" area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Say you've defined a zoom behavior:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', update);
```

When you apply the zoom behavior to a selection, you can unregister the event listeners that it uses internally to detect and respond to certain interactions. In your case, you'd want to do something like this:

```
selection.call(zoom)
    .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
    .on("touchstart.zoom", null)
    .on("touchmove.zoom", null)
    .on("touchend.zoom", null);
```

I'm not sure you want to remove the touch events. Doing so might eliminate double tap zooming. You should experiment with those.

Comment: For my case I just did: `d3.select('svg').on('mousedown.zoom',null);`

Comment: To re-enable panning, just do selection.call(zoom);

Comment: This does not work on d3 v4. It seems that zoom and drag are separate events (`d3.zoom()`, `d3.drag()`) so this is no longer an issue going forward. (Just don't define `d3.drag().on("drag", function(){})`)

Answer (score 4):

I guess it would be good sharing the workaround I found to deal with this problem. What I did is to use the listener on the start of the brush to "deactivate" the zoom:

```
zoom.on("zoom",null);
selection.call(zoom);
```

and activate it again on the *brushend* event.

There is one more trick to take into account and comes from the fact that it is important to save the *scale* and *transition* values of the last valid zoom interaction, so that you use those values when activating the brush on the *brushend* event like this

```
zoom.scale(lastEventScale).translate(lastEventTranslate).on("zoom",drawZoom);
selection.call(scatterZoom);
```

I would love hearing other more "elegant" solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found was to stick a rect element in front of the zoom-enabled element (they must be siblings) and set its fill to 'transparent', when I wanted to disable zoom interaction or to 'none', when I wanted to enable zoom interaction. It looked something like this:

```
if (chart._disableZoom) {
    var rootPanel = d3.select('.rootPanel'); // this is the parent of the element that can be zoomed and panned
    if (!rootPanel.select('.stopEventPanel').node()) { // create panel if it doesn't exist yet
       //.stopEventPanel is appended next to the zoom-enabled element
        rootPanel.append('rect').attr('class', 'stopEventPanel').attr('width', renderConfig.width).attr('height', renderConfig.height).attr('fill', 'transparent');
    } else { // disable zoom and pan
        rootPanel.select('.stopEventPanel').attr('fill', 'transparent');
    }
} else { // enable zoom and pan
    d3.select('.rootPanel').select('.stopEventPanel').attr('fill', 'none');
}
```