# d3 zoom: disable mouse drag?

Tags: user-interface, d3.js, zooming, visualization

I want zoom + brush on a bar chart. I was able to implement zooming ok: [demo here](http://yeaseul.github.io/MailPlus/test.html), but I found out that after zooming, when you mouse down to drag, the bar chart moves. I don't want the bar chart to move on mouse drag. I want the bar chart to stay in its original place and I want to use the mouse drag for brushing. The bar chart could probably scroll left and right, but it should not be dragged left and right.

How do I make the bar chart stay in its original place?

My code snippet is below. [Full script here (134 lines)](http://yeaseul.github.io/MailPlus/js/timeline.js)

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .scaleExtent([0.8, 10])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  // scale x axis
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

  // scale the bars
  var width_scaled = columnwidth * d3.event.scale;
  svg.selectAll(".bargroup rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.date) - width_scaled/2;})
    .attr("width", width_scaled);
}

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .on("brush", brushed);

function brushed() {
  //console.log(brush.extent());
}

var svg = d3.select("#timeline").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height + 7);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom

Comment: @CherryQu how did you solved it?

Comment: `selection.call(zoom).on("mousedown.zoom", null)` disable mouse drag