# How to create Zoom, Drag functions in D3.js without default call functions d3.behavior.zoom() and d3.behavior.drag()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, drag

I have been working with D3.js graph in force layout. I have been using Leap Motion device with javascript language.

My problem is that I'm not able to create Zoom and drag functions which do NOT use default methods written for mouse like d3.behavior.zoom(), d3.behavior.drag().

For example I have this method for Zoom:

```
 function zoom(graph) {
    graph.zoom =
        d3.behavior.zoom()
            .x(graph.x)
            .y(graph.y)
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
            .on("zoom", function () {
                if (d3.event) {
                    graph.scale = d3.event.scale;
                    graph.translate = d3.event.translate;
                    graph.scaledNormalLength = graph.defaultNormalLength / graph.scale;
                }

                d3.select("svg").selectAll(".router").each(function (d) {
                    if ((graph.scale <= graph.zoomShrinkCondition && d.physicalRole == "router") || (graph.scale > graph.zoomShrinkCondition && d.physicalRole == "cloud"))
                        if (d.locked == undefined || !d.locked) {
                            graph.nodeZoom(d);
                        }
                });

                //remove tooltip
                graph.mouseOut();
                //calculate positions - graph will freeze without this
                graph.tick();


            });
}
```

and this function for drag

```
function drag(graph) {
    graph.drag =
        d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("dragstart", function (d) {
                d.fixed = true;
                d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on("drag", function (d) {
                //remove tooltip
                graph.mouseOut();

                //compute coordinates of dragged node (NOTE: if some coordinates are wrong, it is probably because of simulate() function)
                d.px += d3.event.dx / graph.scale;
                d.py += d3.event.dy / graph.scale;

                //compute coordinate of children if they are not hidden
                if (d.physicalRole == "router") {
                    setNodePosition(d, d3.event);
                }

                //compute coordinates of children if they are hidden
                if (d.physicalRole == "cloud") {
                    d._children.forEach(function (ch) {
                        ch.px += d3.event.dx / graph.scale;
                        ch.py += d3.event.dy / graph.scale;
                        setNodePosition(ch, d3.event);
                    });
                }
                graph.getForce().resume()
            });

    function setNodePosition(node, event) {
        if (node.children)
            node.children.forEach(function (ch) {
                setNodePosition(ch, event);
                ch.px += event.dx / graph.scale;
                ch.py += event.dy / graph.scale;
            })
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to create this methods without calling d3.behavior functions? Thanks a lot for yours ideas.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by not calling the default functions?

Comment: I would like to create zoom function, which has same effect as zoom(graph) function which I had show here. But I cannot use behavior functions, because I do not use mouse for controll. I would like to use leap motion to cotroll graph.

Comment: And I would like to create also drag function, which could move graph at different position without using mouse. Only with leap motion. Do you think is it possible? I think d3.js library does not have any function which i could use here.

Comment: My graph does not simulate fingers position, as you did in your example. My graph simulate network topology and hands are used only for controll not for creating content of the graph.

Comment: You don't need to create your own for that, you can simply disable the event listeners you don't need. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom).