# D3: remap mousewheel to be panning gesture instead of zoom gesture

Tags: javascript, d3.js

By default, when you create a new zoom behavior in D3, it maps the mousewheel to control zoom level.  You can also click and drag to pan the chart if it's larger than the chart area.  I'd like to remap the mousewheel gesture to instead pan on the vertical axis (mousewheel up pans up, mousewheel down pans down).  Anyone have any clue how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can disable/remap the events as outlined in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom).

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, that's very useful information.  I still need information on how exactly to write my own handler which will pan north and south, but this is a great starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here we go:
Based on [Lars' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom), we can specify event handler for mousewheel event. As shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom), we start by mapping `wheel.zoom` event to a custom handler `pan`

```
selection.call(zoomer)
      .on("wheel.zoom",pan) // handler function for mousewheel zoom
```

Second, we need to define the pan gesture, which is basically a `translate` in *x* and/or *y* direction.

```
function pan() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + [dx,dy] + ")");
}
```

We also need to quantify the movement in both directions, and relate it to mousewheel movement. By inspecting the details of `MouseWheel` event, we find two useful attributes *deltaX* and *deltaY*, indicating how much the mousewheel moved in each direction.

The final `pan` function is as follows

```
function pan() {
    current_translate = d3.transform(svg.attr("transform")).translate;
    dx = d3.event.wheelDeltaX + current_translate[0];
    dy = d3.event.wheelDeltaY + current_translate[1];
    
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + [dx,dy] + ")");
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyuz5fje/) and [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/ahmohamed/82ac20ccc949470e3206) also modifying Mike's [geometric zoom example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999).

### Cross-browser support:

It seems that mousewheel events differs between browsers. For Safari and Firefox support, you need to add the following:

```
selection.call(zoomer)
  .on("wheel.zoom",pan) 
  .on("mousewheel.zoom", pan)
  .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", pan)
```

Also, the interpretation of `wheelDelta` is reversed in Firefox. `wheelDelta` can be fixed by [this function](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/)

```
function crossWheelDelta()
  // cross-browser wheel delta
  var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
  return Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what to do with crossWheelDelta() where would I utilize this function?

Answer (score 6):

You can also intercept wheel events in the function you create with [`d3.behavior.zoom()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#zoom). "Zoom" events are triggered on both wheel scroll and mouse drag by default, so one potential strategy is to just wait for zoom events and intercept the wheel events within the zoom function.

For example, here's an approach to doing Y translations with both wheel scroll and mouse drag:

```
var panYOnScrollAndDrag = d3.behavior.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([1, 1]) // prevents wheel events (or anything) from changing the scale
   .on("zoom", function() {
      if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "wheel") {
         // use the `d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY` value to translate
         // e.g., yTranslation += yTranslationDelta;
      } else if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "mousemove") {
         // use the normal d3.event.translate array to translate
         // e.g., yTranslation = d3.event.translate[1];
      }
      container.attr("transform", "translate(0," + yTranslation + ")");
   });
```

Then you can throw this function at the relevant d3 container like so, `selection.call(panYOnScrollAndDrag)`, and all the logic is contained in that one function.