# Is it possible to have a floating x-axis on a d3js grapgh?

Tags: d3.js

Have a graph that is very long. And I have the x-axis on the top of the graph. Was wondering if it is possible to have a floating x-axis so when the user scrolls down the graph the x-axis stays on the screen for the user to see?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603796/d3-remap-mousewheel-to-be-panning-gesture-instead-of-zoom-gesture

Answer (score 0):

In most case in d3js,
developers create a single svg element. But you can separate them; eg. x/y axis  and data drawing area. And then You can assign this svg field statically via css to be constant.

```
var axisSvg = d3js.select('axisSvg').append('svg').attr('class','axisSvg);
```

`var mainSvg = d3js.select('mainSvg').append('svg').attr('class','maingSvg);`

and in css

```
 .axisSvg{
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```