# d3.behavior.zoom disable double tap behaviour

Tags: javascript, mobile, d3.js

I'm just getting to grips with D3 and it's graphics ability to create shapes etc. for a mobile app, and I've got the zoom working great on a desktop and managed to remove the double click to zoom behaviour by following this answer: [How to disable double click zoom for d3.behavior.zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom?lq=1)

Is there a way to disable it for mobile devices (double tap)? The double tap zoom is also stopping the double tap event on shapes from triggering, so if I can't disable the double click zoom, is there a way to make sure all events fire on double tap rather tahn just the zoom (double click on the desktop behaves as expected)?

Thanks very much,
Becky

Comment: Preventing an action on double tap is actually tricky because there's no double tap event as such -- D3 compares the time of the previous event to the current one to figure that out. Have you considered the [drag behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) instead if you don't need zoom?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do need the zoom to work, but I can't get any double tap events to fire inside the zoomable window because of the double tap to zoom behaviour, so I want pinch to zoom to work, but double tap zoom not to. Would some sequence of dragstart and e.PreventDefault do any good?

Comment: From looking at the source of the zoom behaviour, you would actually need to modify that. On mobile, all you get are touch events and it does it's own thing to figure out what's actually going on. Obviously you can't disable touch events, which is the only thing you could do here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that on mobile devices zoom should be done with a pinch gesture, you can try detecting the number of fingers in your zoom handler, like that:

```
if (d3.event.sourceEvent.touches.length == 1) 
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

D3 controls the `touchstart.zoom` event on the element you've selected to zoom with `d3.behavior.zoom()()`.  You can't simply replace this handler and conditionally call the original D3 handler because part of it's algorithm adds and removes this handler, so your override would be overwritten.

However, you can catch this event further upstream and conditionally allow it to propagate to the element with the zoom behavior.  For this to work, you need to add your handler to a child element(s) so that it will bubble up to the zooming element.  For example:

```
<g class="zoom_area">  <-- Element you called D3 zoom behaviour on
  <rect width=... height=... style="visibility:hidden; pointer-events:all" class="background">
    // Background rect that will catch all touch events missed by your elements
  </rect>
  <g class="content"> <-- Container for your elements
    ...  <-- Your SVG content
  </g>
</g>
```

Setup the normal D3 zoom behaviour:

```
var zoomer = d3.behavior.zoom();
zoomer(d3.select('g.zoom_area'));
```

Then setup your double touch override:

```
var last_touch_time = undefined;
var touchstart = function() {
    var touch_time = d3.event.timeStamp;
    if (touch_time-last_touch_time < 500 && d3.event.touches.length===1) {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        last_touch_time = undefined;
        return;
    }
    last_touch_time = touch_time;
};
d3.select('.background_rect').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
d3.select('.content').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
```

Here is an alternative version that will only detect rapid touches where the tap occurs in a similar location.  The downside is that rapid taps in different locations will still zoom-in.  The upside is that rapid legitimate panning/zooming gestures will still work.

```
var last_touch_event = undefined;
var touchstart = function() {
    if (last_touch_event && d3.event.touches.length===1 &&
        d3.event.timeStamp - last_touch_event.timeStamp < 500 &&
        Math.abs(d3.event.touches[0].screenX-last_touch_event.touches[0].screenX) < 10 &&
        Math.abs(d3.event.touches[0].screenY-last_touch_event.touches[0].screenY) < 10) {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        last_touch_time = undefined;
    }
    last_touch_event = d3.event;
};
d3.select('.background_rect').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
d3.select('.content').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
```

With this approach, I've seen the `dblclick` event triggered as normal for a double-tap.