# D3 Prevent Double Click Zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a D3 Network Graph and I am trying to disable the Double Click zoom function.
I have it zooming using:

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom]);
    zoom.on("zoom", function() {
            g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        });
   svg.call(zoom)
```

However I cant seem to be able to disable just the Double click zoom. When I use the code below it disables the zoom altogether.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom]);
zoom.on("zoom", function() {
            g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")").on("dblclick.zoom", null);
        });
   svg.call(zoom)
```

I have also tried calling

```
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
```

on the svg element by itself and that doesnt work either.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom)? `dblclick.zoom` should work.

Comment: Yes i have, it doesn't seem to work for me. thanks

Comment: Works fine for me, random jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SD5cK/14/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to call

```
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
```

after

```
    svg.call(zoom)
```

i.e.

```
    svg.call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```