# d3.behavior.zoom disable double tap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not sure if this is possible, but I would like to disable the zoom behavior on double tap, and keep the pinch-zoom behavior when using on tablet. I would like to use this event for other functionality.
If I disable "touchstart.zoom" event I am loosing the whole zooming functionality.

Comment: I think you can remove all the listeners for the `dblclick` event. I'm blanking on the syntax at the moment, but it's something that's possible. Update: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom

Comment: Yes, unregistering "dblclick.zoom" event works for double click, but not also for double tap on touch device.

Comment: Is there not a corresponding double "tap" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 controls the `touchstart.zoom` event on the element you've selected to zoom with `d3.behavior.zoom()()`.  You can't simply replace this handler and conditionally call the original D3 handler because part of it's algorithm adds and removes this handler, so your override would be overwritten.

However, you can catch this event further upstream and conditionally allow it to propagate to the element with the zoom behavior.  For this to work, you need to add your handler to a child element(s) so that it will bubble up to the zooming element.  For example:

```
<g class="zoom_area">  <-- Element you called D3 zoom behaviour on
  <rect width=... height=... style="visibility:hidden; pointer-events:all" class="background">
    // Background rect that will catch all touch events missed by your elements
  </rect>
  <g class="content"> <-- Container for your elements
    ...  <-- Your SVG content
  </g>
</g>
```

Setup the normal D3 zoom behaviour:

```
var zoomer = d3.behavior.zoom();
zoomer(d3.select('g.zoom_area'));
```

Then setup your double touch override:

```
var last_touch_time = undefined;
var touchstart = function() {
    var touch_time = d3.eent.timeStamp;
    if (touch_time-last_touch_time < 500 and d3.event.touches.length===1) {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        last_touch_time = undefined;
    }
    last_touch_time = touch_time;
};
d3.select('.background_rect').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
d3.select('.content').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
```

Here is an alternative version that will only detect rapid touches where the tap occurs in a similar location.  The downside is that rapid taps in different locations will still zoom-in.  The upside is that rapid legitimate panning/zooming gestures will still work.

```
var last_touch_event = undefined;
var touchstart = function() {
    if (last_touch_event && d3.event.touches.length===1 &&
        d3.event.timeStamp - last_touch_event.timeStamp < 500 &&
        Math.abs(d3.event.touches[0].screenX-last_touch_event.touches[0].screenX) < 10 &&
        Math.abs(d3.event.touches[0].screenY-last_touch_event.touches[0].screenY) < 10) {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        last_touch_time = undefined;
    }
    last_touch_event = d3.event;
};
d3.select('.background_rect').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
d3.select('.content').on('touchstart.zoom', touchstart);
```