# Zoom touch on mobile with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I constructed a chart with the library D3, now I need to have a zoom with the touch on the x axis and not with the double click as I noticed looking on the internet.
I ask you to do it? And if it were possible if there is an example where you can learn how to do.
Thanks so much.
dave

---

Unfortunately I could not zoom in at all!

I copied all on: https://jsfiddle.net/1y408pzo/1/

where when I click to zoom (mobile will be managed with the touch) me everything disappears ...

```
function redraw() {


zoom.x(x);

  d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .ease("linear");
  svg.select(".xAxis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".yAxis").call(yAxis);
  svg.select(".grid").call(make_y_axis().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(""));
  svg.select(".data1").attr("d", lineFunction(data));
}
```

to redraw the graph, but it does not draw anything!

I do not know what to do...

Comment: are you going to pay someone to do it ? If so, this isn't the site for that. Show us what you have tried and we will point you in the right direction. We are not here to do your work, but more to, like I said, point you in the right direction and show you where you have gone wrong

Comment: I have not asked to do my job, but I asked for an example to learn, if I hurt explained I apologize! I have not done any work on the zoom, because I could not find any type that will work for my case ... I repeat I apologize if someone has got it wrong!

Comment: No need to apologise, you know now :P as for the zoom look at these: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708 https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior the first one is the zoom and pan together, the second is actually how the zoom behaviour works. For yours, you say you want zoom on click of x axis ? Attach an event listener ('click') on the xaxis and toggle zoom (i.e toggle the scale, say between 1 and 2 so it zooms in and out. You do need to give us more information on exactly what you want. The no double click is easily found online

Comment: Here's an example ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null);

Answer (score 2):

well, I did it!
it was hard work, the result is here: https://jsfiddle.net/1y408pzo/9/

Zoom is given:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom ()
.scaleExtent ([1, 12])
.x (x)
.on ('zoom', zoomHandler function () {

svg.select ('. x.axis')
.call (xAxis);

svg.selectAll ('. data1, circle'). attr ('transform', 'translate (' + d3.event.translate [0] + ', 0)'
+ 'Scales (' + d3.event.scale + ', 1)');

});
```

While the 'defs' object takes to not let out the graph in addition to the axes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information you want on line.

For example the zoom :

Zoom and pan together : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

How zoom works : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior

The prevent double click like you said : [How to disable double click zoom for d3.behavior.zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786023/how-to-disable-double-click-zoom-for-d3-behavior-zoom)

Works like so : `d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null);`

You say you want to zoom on click on the x axis ? Kind of need more information on what you actually want. Do you want to toggle zoom ? If so something like this :

```
xaxis.on('click', toggleZoom);

var zoomIn = false;

function toggleZoom() {
  var thisScale;
  if (zoomIn) {
    thisScale = 1;
    zoomIN = false;
  } else {
    thisScale = 2;
    zoomIn = true;
  }
  //container is your container of the chart, not your axis
  container.attr("transform", "scale(" + thisScale + ")");
}
```

Basically this works by checking if you zoomed in already, if you haven't zoom in by scale of 2, if you have zoomed in, zoom our back to original.